# Bloque for siempre da 0

Tags: vb6

Tengo esta función que pretende convertir de octal a decimal. El problema es que siempre da 0 y no se como corregirla.

```
Public Function OctToDec(ByVal octal As Long) As Integer
    Dim DecNum As Integer
    Dim digito As Integer
    
    Const DIVISOR As Integer = 10
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim octal As Long
    Dim j As Long
    
    j = 0
    i = octal
    
    numero = 0
    digito = 0
    
    For i = octal To 0 Step -1
        i = i \ DIVISOR
        
        If Not (digito >= 0 And digito <= 7) Then
           Exit Sub
        End If

        digito = CInt(i) Mod DIVISOR
        j = j + 1
        DecNum = DecNum + digito * CInt(8 ^ j)
        
    Next
    OctToDec = DecNum
End Function
```

Comment: bueno pues tu logica esta mal.. digito = 0, entonces digito >= 0 es true, digito >= 7 es false... el and da false.. el not de false es true... entonces exit sub con valor 0

Comment: haciendo debug del codigo, esto salia solo :(

Comment: El error no está en en if

Comment: Puse <=7 no >=7

Comment: si... y el error esta totalmente en el if... que haya copiado mal el dato en mi comentario no invalida que tu if no funcione...

Comment: No está en el If te estoy escribiendo. Si le sacas el If va a dar 0 igual. Ahora que estoy pensando está mal la condición del For

Comment: la depuraste? esto sale solo si la depuras...

Comment: Lo estoy depurando

Comment: Tiene Exit Sub cuando está dentro de un Function.

Comment: Aunque el código publicado no compila, si lo hiciera sólo devolvería cero con números de 1 dígito por causa de la división `i = i \ DIVISOR`. Debes encontrar otra manera de descomponer el número octal dado en cada uno de sus dígitos.

Comment: la variable `octal` está duplicada. Ese `Exit sub` no pinta nada ahí.  Te recomiendo que añadas `Option Explicit`¿Podrías, por favor, especificar cuál es el resultado que esperas con algunos ejemplos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenías muchas cosas mal puestas, entre variables que no se usaban a otros elementos que tampoco estaban bien o en mal lugar...

Así parece que funciona...

```
Public Function OctToDec(ByVal octal As Long) As Integer
    Dim DecNum As String = 0
    Dim digito As Integer = 0
    Const DIVISOR As Integer = 10
    Dim i As Long = 0

    digito = 0

    For i = octal To octal Step -1
        i = i \ DIVISOR
        digito = CInt(i) Mod DIVISOR

        If (digito <= 0 And digito >= 7) Then
            Exit For
        End If

        DecNum = DecNum + CInt(8 * i)

    Next
    OctToDec = DecNum
End Function
```